# login and security system with Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I need to make a java program with a security and a login system for a project at school

I was thinking of using a enum for the security role in java with a security level:

```
public enum Role {

lECTOR(0), COORDINATOR(1), ADMINISTRATOR(2);

private int securityLevel;

Role(int securityLevel) {
    this.securityLevel = securityLevel;
}

public int returnSecurityLevel() {
    return securityLevel;
}
```

In mysql I'm thinking of making two tables

```
table users with a userid, username, password and security_id

roles with a security_id, rolename  this table I would link to the enum
```

depending on the securitylevel I would then say what a specific user can or can't do.

Is this a good way to work or not, any suggestions are more then welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider if you really need a separate table for the enum. Maybe just have a column for it in the user table.

The only reason to keep it a separate table is if a user can have multiple roles.

Comment: through the security system I had in mind that a user could have just one role, because the "higher" you go in securitylevel the more stuff you can do.  So I can just integrate the one table in the other ... ?

Comment: Yes. Just look into how to store passwords in a secure way and how to avoid SQL injection.